# how to convert string value to html element using angular?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I've tried bind a one page html to model window by angular HTTP call and ng-bind-html tag also included the **ngSanitize** js core. but It is working without  HTML element.
My Code: HTML

```
<div class="myModels" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="true" ng-show="showModel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" ng-bind-html = "ModelContent"></div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.Login = function(path){
    $http.post('http:'+path).success(function(result){$scope.ModelContent = result;})
}
```

Render HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-model="">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="10" class="form-control" ng-model=""> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15" class="form-control" ng-model=""> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button name="SignIn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> You can refer below image it doesn't showing HTML elements
>   [image]

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the source for [the `$sanitize` whitelist](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L250), it looks like `input` elements are not allowed by default.

You could add them to the whitelist, but in this case the HTML is coming from your server and I would expect it to be trustworthy. So the simplest solution would be to [use `$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to allow all elements in your HTML.

To do that, you would change your `Login` function like so:

```
// Note that you'll need to inject $sce into your controller
$scope.Login = function(path){
    $http.post('http:'+path)
    .success(function(result) {
        $scope.ModelContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your controller 
controller.js

```
$rootScope.errorMessage = 'Account activated successfully, please <a href="/">Login</a> and other <em>stuff</em> with your username and password';
```

Also use this code in your html page

```
<h5 ng-bind-html="errorMessage"></h5>
```

Comment: Already I've tried ng-bind-html and ng-bind template. It doesn't work

Comment: can you change $scope.ModelContent to $rootScope.ModelContent

Comment: this is a small example of bind html http://plnkr.co/edit/mziacJZj2rFwo5c4fRtO?p=preview